# Define A UDF with Generic Type and Extra Parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to define a UDF in scala spark like the pseudo code below:

```
def transformUDF（size:Int）:UserDefinedFunction = udf((input:Seq[T]){

  if (input != null)
    Vectors.dense(input.map(_.toDouble).toArray)
  else
    Vectors.dense(Array.fill[Double](size)(0.0))

})
```

if `input` is not null, cast every element to Double Type.
if `input` is null, return a all-zero vector.

And I want `T` to be limited to numeric type, like java.lang.Number in Java. But it seems that `Seq[java.lang.Number]` cannot work with the `toDouble`.

Is there any appropriate way?

Comment: Instead of T in input:Seq[T],specify that Seq[java.lang.Number]

Comment: try `def transformUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf((size: Int, input:Seq[java.lang.Number]) => {
      if (input != null)
        Vectors.dense(input.map(_.doubleValue()).toArray)
      else
        Vectors.dense(Array.fill[Double](size)(0.0))
    })` this should work I guess

Comment: @Sakalya Thank you for your answer. I had tried it, but it did not work with `toDouble`. Ramesh's answer works.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan `doubleValue` works! Thank you! With this solution, I should add a new column which would be just `lit(size)`. `def transformUDF(size: Int): UserDefinedFunction = udf(( input:Seq[java.lang.Number]) => { if (input != null) Vectors.dense(input.map(_.doubleValue()).toArray) else Vectors.dense(Array.fill[Double](size)(0.0)) })` this might work better without adding a new column. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right . You would need lit(size) to be passed to the udf function. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my working comment as

```
def transformUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf((size: Int, input:Seq[java.lang.Number]) => {
  if (input != null)
    Vectors.dense(input.map(_.doubleValue()).toArray)
  else
    Vectors.dense(Array.fill[Double](size)(0.0))
})
```

You don't need to create a new column, you can just pass it to the udf function as

```
dataframe.withColumn("newCol", transformUDF(lit(the size you want), dataframe("the column you want to transform")))
```

Comment: Very good answer. And `dataframe.withColumn("newCol", transformUDF(the size I want)($"the column you want to transform"))` also works without using a column~~

Comment: great to hear that. :) it would be even greater if you accept the answer. :) and an upvote when eligible